# Relacionar ID com nome na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

preciso de uma ajuda.

Tenho uma tabela de categorias que possui os campos:

- id;
- nome;
- descricao;
- id_categoria_pai;
- id_user;

Quero pegar o nome da categoria quando o id_categoria_pai for igual ao id da categoria.

Exemplo:

A categoria Carro possui como pai a categoria Veículos
id = 4;
nome = Carro;
descricao = qualquer;
id_categoria_pai = 1(veiculos);
id_user = 1;

Preciso exibir o nome da categoria pai, nesse caso, Veiculos.

Como eu consigo fazer isso? Tentei de todo jeito e não consigo.

Ou eu crio as tabelas separadas? acho que nao ne.

Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode utilizar join, + ou - assim: SELECT * FROM categorias as cat LEFT JOIN categorias_pai as cat_pai ON cat_pai.id = cat.id_categoria_pai; Claro, você precisa alterar para a sua situação e nomes de tabela em fim...

Comment: Cara, to meio perdido hehe, mas isso vai funcionar na mesma tabela?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi sua pergunta... o que acontece nesse caso, ele vai selecionar tudo das tabelas categorias_pai e categorias, quando o id da categorias_pai for o mesmo que id_categoria_pai da tabela categorias...; Desculpe é meio confuso mesmo, qual o nome de suas tabelas? Pode fornecer elas em sua pergunta? Assim ficaria mais fácil para ajudar;

Comment: Mas só existe uma tabela, a tabela categorias, dentro dela possui o campo id e id_categoria_pai, ou seja as categorias pai e filhas estão na mesma tabela

Comment: Ah... entendi, então ficaria + ou  - assim (Eu teria feito separado, mas tudo bem, sem problemas). SELECT * FROM categorias as cat1 LEFT JOIN categorias as cat2 ON cat2.id = cat1.id_categoria_pai WHERE cat1.id=1; Teste esse sql e diga se funciona... mas acredito que para melhor manutenção seria interessante separar, (categorias) e (subcategorias);

Comment: Funcionou perfeito Rafael, obrigado pela ajuda, mas pensei no que você falou e vou separar, obrigado.

Comment: Perfeito, forneci como resposta a solução para que não seja perdida caso aconteça alguma coisa com os comentários;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando o que o usuário forneceu de informações (categorias pai e filhas estão na mesma tabela) a solução para o caso seria mais ou menos a seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM categorias as cat1 LEFT JOIN categorias as cat2 ON cat2.id = cat1.id_categoria_pai WHERE cat1.id=1;
```

Porém o interessante seria separar as tabelas em **categorias e subcategorias** para melhor manutenção e entendimento;